# Devops Get AAD api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to get the devops azure active directory name or id?

[image]

I'm wondering how to get the aad name or id so that i can display them on my application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the api from network tab in dev tools

[image]

similarly you will be able to get the azure ad name from url like below

https://####.visualstudio.com/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery

Json you would be receiving , from that you will be able to get it in `orgnizationTenantData` node.

Hope it helps.